# Link element disobeying liquid layout causing link image to appear wrongly

Tags: html, css

I am a novice at HTML & CSS and I am trying to create my first static website from scratch.

I have a div element which contains an inline list of 2 elements, each containing a link with an image.

All sizes are expressed in percentages, and from the div element on, everything is just made to fit in its containing element. Only the list split the div in 2.

Even though the link element is specified to max-width = 100% and max-height = 100%, it is rendered outside of its containing li element, when I inspect in Firefox. 
This causes the image it contains to appear outside of the list and thus outside of the box.

How can I make sure the link and the image fit inside the li box?

EDIT: added HTML & CSS elements

Relevant HTML

```
<div id="delivery">
    <div id="ta">
        Bagel<br/>Angels
    </div>
    <div id="tu">
        <ul id="take" >
            <li class="delivery"><a href="link" class="delivery">
                <img src="images/deliveroo.svg" alt="Deliveroo delivery" class="delivery" id="deliveroo">
            </a></li>
            <li class="delivery"><a href="link" class="delivery">
                <img src="images/Takeaway.svg" alt="Takeaway delivery" class="delivery" id="takeaway">
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tb">
        <span>Bagel<br/>Angels</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS: I use the media tag for desktop view en this is were the problem occurs, everything works as expected on mobile.

```
div#delivery {
    position: fixed;
    border-style:  ridge ridge ridge none;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, lightgray , white);
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%; 
}

div#ta {
    margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%; 
    text-align: center;
}

div#tb {
    display: none;
}

ul#take {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img#deliveroo {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

img#takeaway {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

li.delivery {
    margin: 10% 0% 0% 0%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    div#delivery {
        /* left: -24%; */  
        transition: 0.3s;

        width: 40%;
        height: 10%;
        bottom: 40%;
    }

    div#delivery:hover {
        left: 0;
    }

    div#ta {
        display: none;
    }

    div#tb {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
    }

    div#tb span {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    div#tu {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    ul#take {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    li.delivery {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }

    a.delivery {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    img#deliveroo {
        display: inline-block;
        width: initial;
        height: initial;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    img#takeaway {
        width: initial;
        height: initial;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

I know I overuse ID's here, but I will reformat later once I know it can do what I want.

Comment: Can you please create a HTML snippet?

Comment: I added all relevant code.